# Indexing in multidimensional arrays in numpy library

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> y = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)
>>> y[1:5:2,::3]
array([[ 7, 10, 13],
       [21, 24, 27]])
```

What does `y[1:5:2,::3]` mean? In detail.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for reading the tutorial

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's not written here https://numpy.org/

Comment: No, but it is [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: But, FWIW, I find it difficult to unpack what it's doing from just viewing it. Hopefully the code has good reason for using this

Comment: It's take every other row starting with `1`, e.g. 1 and 3.  And every third column, 0,3,6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the details of [`Python slicing notation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) here.

---

Your case combines slicing notation with numpy notation : `y[1:5:2,::3]` is leans slicing `1:5:2` in 1st dimension, and `::3` in 2nd dimension

```
# Initial array
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [28 29 30 31 32 33 34]]
```

- `1:5:2` take from values `[1;5[` and one over 2, this, in the first dimension, so it keeps values `1` and `3` (you can say *rows*)

  ```
  [[ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
   [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]]
  ```
- `::3` takes all elements are the 2 first values are not provided, but just one over three, in the second dimension

  ```
  [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13] => [ 7 10 13] # one over 3
  ```

Comment: I have no idea what this means. I think the language needs to be a lot clearer